# solution of expression with error function.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus

$\beta \,e^{\beta^2}\text{erf} (\beta) = \frac{St_e}{\sqrt{\pi}}$.

where $\text{erf}$ is error function and $St_e$ is any number. How we can find $\beta\,$?

Answer (score 2):

I do not think that an anlytical solution could be found for the zero of 
$$f(x)=x \,e^{x^2}\, \text{erf}(x)-a$$ and you need to consider numerical methods.

Since the function varies very fast, I suggest you look for the zero of
$$g(x)=\log \left(x \,e^{x^2}\, \text{erf}(x)\right)-\log(a)$$ which is much nicer.

Let us suppose $a=1000$. A plot of function $g(x)$ shows that the solution is somewhere between $2$ and $3$. So, let us start Newton method using $x_0=2$ to see what happens. The following iterates would be obtained
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 2.000000000 \\
 1 & 2.490911880 \\
 2 & 2.452084322 \\
 3 & 2.451825473 \\
 4 & 2.451825461
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

*After JJacquelin answer.*

For small value of $x$, Taylor expansion gives
$$f(x)=-\log(a)+\left( \log (x^2)+\log \left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi }}\right)\right)+\frac{2
   x^2}{3}+O\left(x^4\right)$$ Ignoring the higher order terms, the approximate solution will express in terms of Lambert function.
$$x^2=\frac{3}{2} W\left(\frac{a \,\sqrt{\pi } }{3}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\beta \,e^{\beta^2}\text{erf} (\beta) = \frac{St_e}{\sqrt{\pi}}$$
As far as I know, there is no closed form for the roots of this equation.

For small values of $\beta$, i.e. small values of $St_e$ , one can expand to series :
$$St_e\simeq 2\beta^2+\frac43\beta^4+\frac{8}{15}\beta^6+\frac{16}{105}\beta^8+...$$

The inverse series is :
$$\beta\simeq\sqrt{\frac{St_e}{2}}\left(1-\frac16 St_e +\frac{23}{360} (St_e)^2-\frac{157}{5040}(St_e)^3+\frac{31933}{1814400}(St_e)^4+... \right)$$
This series approximate is valid for $0\leq St_e<1$, not for large $St_e$ . See the valuable answer from Claude Leibovici.